# A Christmas puzzle: $n$ children in a row identifying the colors of their hats

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $n$ children are placed in a row from north to south such that all of them look at north; i.e., every child does only see the children before him. After being placed in the row, they aren't allow to move or communicate in any form possible.
>
> Every child will have a random bobble hat marked with a color in $0, \dots, k$, with $k \leq n - 1$ on his head. Noone knows which color its hat has, and noone is allowed to look after.
>
> After all children have their hats, they shall say which color his hat has. They are only allowed to say "color $i$". If more than one child will say the wrong color, no one gets a present.
>
> What is the winning strategy for the children?

I think it could have something to do with the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem). Otherwise, I can only imagine to speak rhythmically to encode the number of combination, but that seems not to be intended.

Comment: Does the child which sees all the other starts first?

Answer (score 3):

The child who sees all the others starts and says the sum of all colors he/she sees, modulo $n.$ Then the second one can subtract the sum of the colors he/she sees from that number, does the modulo $n$ calculation and knows their own color and says it. The third child subtracts the sum of the colors he/she sees and the color of the second child from the first said number and so on. Continuing this way, everyone but the first child will say the correct number.